# Accessing AWS s3 files only from React Native App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm creating a react native app, which is using images and audiofiles from an AWS S3 bucket.

I use rails and carrierwave in the backend to upload images and audiofiles from the users.

But, I need the files to be only accessible by the users of the mobile app in some way.

I figured I would use a signed url, but this link can only last 7 days maximum, which is not working for this app. The files should be available until a deadline which could be anytime in the future.

Is there some way in AWS to say that these files can be viewed by everyone (or just the app) but not be downloaded? The reason I wan't this, is that the users should be able to decide if the audiofile is downloadable or not.

After finding out the signed url's are not valid longer than 7 days, I don't know how to accomplish this (pretty newbie with AWS)

Answer (score 0):

The code is pretty crude as I spend most of my time in Node + Go, but I think it gets the primary point across.

You want to create an endpoint in your API to control playing files. All interaction with the file will be done through this endpoint that way you can control access to the file in any way that you want.

```
class SoundFileController < ActionController::Base
  def getFile


    file = SoundFile.get(params[:fileId])


    //do some validation to determine if you can play the file. 
    //you may want to validate an auth token, or some other 
    //user validation logic that's important to your system here

    if file.is_downloadable
        AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(  )
        url = AWS::S3::S3Object.url_for(file.path, YOUR_BUCKET, :expires_in => 1.minutes)

        redirect_to url
    end 

    //file is not downloadable 
    //return a forbidden message
    raise ActionController::Forbidden

  end 
end
```

Comment: So, when the user clicks a download-button in the app, it should call this getFile-method? 
And it will check if the file is downloadable (in model) before downloading the object?

But my issue is: if the file is not public (downloadable) in s3, then it won't play in the app?
The users should hear the audiofile in the app, and also be restricted download-access if the users declare the file as not downloadable. But if I make it public, anyone with the link can download it, right?